# Can I safely sell the Nuka Cola recipes?

Tags: fallout-4

Once I've collected a Nuka Cola recipe, if I sell it to a vendor will I lose the ability to craft that recipe?  Or can I safely sell the recipes that I've collected?

Comment: Here is what I recommend trying.  Save your game before selling one of the recipes.  Then sell it, and attempt to make that recipe.  If you can't, reload your game.  If you can, then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the magazines, the **recipes will unlock, or permanently add the 'effect'** to your Sole Survivor.

It's safe to sell or drop the item, or place them in a Magazine Rack in your favourite settlement.